# how can i edit heroku app files for discord bots?

Tags: github, heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm stuck at Run error I know how to solve it, I just want to edit app files
like node_modules how I can do such thing?

```js
2021-04-28T15:09:04.098902+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:81
2021-04-28T15:09:04.098924+00:00 app[worker.1]:guild.channels.set(channel.id, channel);
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to edit a internal file? when you could just simply update to v12.5.3
all the versions below `12.5.3` is broken and is not supported (stage channels broke the versions),

and to your question,

here is what i found while searching ,

"The app’s node_modules directory is generated at build time from the dependencies listed in package.json and the lockfile."

this was from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

So as they are being genarated at the build time, it will not matter of what you change in the node_modules it will not be there when you start your app